# How can i transform Image1 to Image2 using matplotlib.pyplot or another library in python

Tags: python, image-processing, filter, matplotlib

How can i transform Image1 to Image2 using matplotlib.pyplot or another library in Python?

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

(This image turned out to be confidential,i removed it because i can't delete the post. Sorry for the inconvenience)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you just looking for a lib in python to process the image, or do you also want the image processing algorithms to de-noise your first image?

Comment: @lennon310 it would simpler for me if there's a ready filter in a lib in python. I already tried several filters in PIL (ImageFilter) and in Gimp but i didn't get any good results. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Blue Shrimp. Have you already got the procedures on how to transform your image1 to 2? Mind sharing it here? Thanks

Comment: @lennon310 Hello, i think the filter that was used was the sobel filter,but i'm not able to have a result that is quiet close to image 2

Comment: seems like you already solved the problem?

Comment: @lennon310 Unfortunately i haven't

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Python Imageing Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (which also has [python bindings](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/), by the way), especially the [ImageFilter](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagefilter.htm) module.

But tools like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) or one of the built-in filters in [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) might be more suitable for experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the experimental data and already filtered from image 1 to image 2 by someone else? I  wonder whether you have the point spread function along with the raw image 1?

Comment: Yes.Image 2 is filtered from Image 1 by someone else.
I don't what point spread function means,so i guess i don't have it.

Comment: very interesting problem attracted me. But I'm just curious, didn't you ask that guy for more imaging processing technique he was using to get your image 2?

Comment: That's what i'll do, but i thought i could find the processing technique on my own. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thank you ! Hope you would update the progress here once you figure out prior to someone else. You can do it simply by answering your own question.